# Is it possible to "wire in" a rechargeable battery or battery bank to another PCB build?

Tags: led, pcb

I am working on making PCBs for LED lanterns all from scratch. Going to start learning pic programming soon to add effects etc, and put it all on a PCB.

How difficult/or possible would it be to attach a small battery bank (something from 5 below etc) to power it, and charge it with a USB?

Instead of using a 2AA battery pack like I have been,this makes more sense, if possible.  Sorry if this is simple or not worded correctly, like I said, absolute beginner here.

Edit- adding a crude drawing of what I hope to accomplish,  not sure if it's "correctly" drawn but the basic idea.

[image]

Comment: Wire in how? Solder a usb cable to your pcb? Solder wires directly to the power bank board? Remove the case and add the battery and pcb inside your case? Yes yes and yes.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of the device you wish to attach of a battery bank? What is the output voltage of the battery pack? What is "5 below etc"?

Comment: I figured I'd try to make a pcb with a chip for controlling the leds, and a USB chargeable (2AA, etc) battery pack usually used for phones (usually found cheap at stores like 5below, a retail store where things are usually under 5$). After doing some research, it seems I may be able to run one wire from the battery pack (not sure how yet) to the pcb, then the other thru a on/off switch then pcb. I will try to upload a very crude schematic tomorrow, I don't know proper electronic blueprints yet. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Oh, you can also either add a usb connector on the pcb or make your pcb a usb connector (a bit more advanced and tricky prospect)

Comment: I saw that but yes it does seem a bit more tricky. I'm still a bit off from learning to program chips for effects but wanted to see if I could sort of "Frankenstein" in a rechargeable battery pack. It seems possible from scratch but for a beginner it might seem easier to wire it all in together? Just a thought

Comment: So after looking around for pcbs etc, would anyone have recommendations for premade or a list of parts for this? To clarify I'm trying to make a pcb with a micro controller to run some leds, but want to have a battery pack that can be charged via USB (phone style) charger, thanks again for all the help so far!

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be possible to dismantle a USB power bank. Extract the battery and control board. Solder wires from the USB output socket to your board, with a switch if required.

Make sure the charging socket is still accessable.

Comment: So if I understand correctly,  I would just remove the outgoing USB port (for outgoing charging) and run wire from that to the incoming power on the LED pcb?

Comment: @Lunchbox does your board run on 5V? If not, you're going to need some voltage regulator.

Comment: One board I was studying ran off a 3.7v battery pack, not sure what kind I plan on using yet, as long a several leds can run off of it. Do you mean resistors, or is a regulator something else entirely? Still learning here

Comment: @Lunchbox If you are designing a PCB with lighting effects, then it's unlikely that a resistor would be enough.  So maybe a voltage regulator.  You need to start thinking about what is going to be doing the flashing, and from that work out what power supply you need.  You seem to be designing the power supply without knowing what it's going to be powering yet.

Comment: when I usually wire up LEDs I use a 2AA battery pack, I'm trying to use a pcb to add effects, but would like to add a rechargeable battery if possible. I just figured that if I could get a Powerbank battery in the same safe range, or configure a whole new setup from scratch, it would work. I've seen some small battery packs that come in that range (3-5v) but am inexperienced in looking for a list of parts to make one from scratch. I.E. a USB charging port that would work with specific battery needs, it's still confusing to me and I don't want to dangerously mismatch parts

Comment: @Lunchbox If you're going to make something from scratch, then look up the datasheets of the chips you're thinking of using, as they will have example circuits.  A bare LiIon cell varies from about 4.2V when charged down to 3.0Vwhen flat.  If that's the right voltage, you need no resistors or regulators, but buying a protected cell is a really good idea.  But you do still need something to charge the cell with.  But I would recommend starting with working out what the flasher circuit is, then deciding how to power it.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge with this, it's saving me trouble in the future I'm sure! I didn't even consider that. I'll get back to researching what would work out best and which parts work together, again it's very appreciated!